# how do I get rid of the secure nonsecure warning on page with iframe under SSL with phishing filter?

Tags: ssl, filter, phishing

I have a page under SSL with an iframe that refreshes itself every 20 seconds through an HTTP refresh prgama. If I browse the site with IE7 and phishing filter enabled I receive secure-nonsecure content warnings in irregular intervals which cease if phishing filter is disabled. Does anybody have an idea what I can do in order to get rid of the warnings even if phishing filter is enabled?

Answer (score 2):

You should make sure the iframe url is using ssl(https).

I'm not sure how the phishing filter in IE works but I would make sure all iframes also comes from the same domain.

I assume that the content you are getting in the iframe is not from your own code.

One way to do both would be to setup a simple web "proxy", an address in your server that only forwards contents from the other website.
This would though increase your server traffic by twice the amount that you visitor today is consuming. However this could be reduced to half by caching the data assuming it is the same for all your visitors.

Answer (score 0):

That's a browser setting in IE7 which you wouldn't be able to enable/disable from your code.  It's something that you'll have to fix so the user doesn't get the message in the first place.

[This may help you.](http://weblogs.asp.net/rchartier/archive/2008/03/12/ie7-this-page-contains-both-secure-and-nonsecure-items.aspx)